# Optimizing a Multithreaded C Program for Processing Large TSV Files

Tags: c, multithreading, posix

**Problem Description**:

I've written a multithreaded C program using POSIX to process three large TSV input files. My goal is to generate output files based on these inputs, but I'm facing performance issues.

- *File 1*: Contains country-key pairs (e.g., African 0\nAmerindian 1\n...).
- *File 2*: A large n x m matrix with single digit values corresponding to keys from File 1.

  Example:

  ```
  0\t3\t4\t1\t2...

  0\t3\t4\t1\t2...
  ```
- *File 3*: Another large matrix (n x m+1), with columns of 0, 1, 9, and an index column of integer values.
  Example:

  ```
  111111\t0\t1\t0\t0\t1...

  222222\t0\t1\t1\t1\t1...
  ```

**Objective**: For each country, I need to create an output file (country.txt) with the same structure as File 3. The output logic depends on matching keys from File 2 with values in File 3.

**Output example**:

For Amerindian.txt with key 1 we copy the first value from File 3, the index, then compare each value to the key value of the specific country. So that we observe a 9 for a mismatch at every position despite position 4 for row in File2 so that at this position we copy the value from File3 which leads to the following output:

```
  111111\t9\t9\t9\t0\t9...

  222222\t9\t9\t9\t1\t9...
```

**Current Approach**:

- I've implemented a multithreaded solution in C.
- The program works but is extremely slow. It takes over 8 hours (estimated by TIME+ in htop) to process 50,000 lines with 17,000 columns using 24 threads. Threads frequently entering disk sleep state indicated by `D` in column S of htop.
- I've tried splitting input files every 50,000 lines to fit into RAM, but this hasn't significantly improved performance.

**Key Code Segment**:

```c
// Main function and processFile function details
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
//... library loading, typedef, declaration, parameter loading, read files into memory

    int currentLine = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; ++i) {

printf("Debug: Allocating ThreadArg for thread %d\n", i);

   threadArgs[i] = (ThreadArg *)malloc(sizeof(ThreadArg));
   int threadLineCount = linesPerThread + (i < remainingLines ? 1 : 0);
   threadArgs[i]->localOriginLines = malloc(sizeof(char *) * threadLineCount);
        threadArgs[i]->startLine = currentLine;
        threadArgs[i]->endLine = currentLine + linesPerThread;
        if (i < remainingLines) threadArgs[i]->endLine++;
        currentLine = threadArgs[i]->endLine;
        threadArgs[i]->specificOriginIndex = specificOriginIndex;
printf("Debug: Thread %d - startLine: %d, endLine: %d, specificOriginIndex: %d\n", i, threadArgs[i]->startLine, threadArgs[i]->endLine, threadArgs[i]->specificOriginIndex);
   if (pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, processFile, threadArgs[i])) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate memory for thread arguments\n");
        
        // Cleanup already allocated resources for threadArgs
        for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j) {
            free(threadArgs[j]);
        }

      goto cleanup;

        return 1; // Exit due to memory allocation failure
    }
}


// Thread joining and data aggregation
for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; ++i) {
    printf("Waiting for Thread %d to finish\n", i);
    char ***threadResult;
    pthread_join(threads[i], (void **)&threadResult);

    // Aggregate data from each thread
    for (int j = threadArgs[i]->startLine; j < threadArgs[i]->endLine && j < txtLineCount; ++j) {
        for (int k = 0; k < originCount; ++k) {
            if (threadResult[k][j] != NULL) {
                originLines[k][j] = strdup(threadResult[k][j]); // Copy data safely
            }
        }
    }

    // Free memory allocated in the thread
    for (int k = 0; k < originCount; ++k) {
        for (int j = 0; j < txtLineCount; ++j) {
            free(threadResult[k][j]);
        }
        free(threadResult[k]);
    }
    free(threadResult); 
    free(threadArgs[i]); // Free the thread argument
}
   printf("Program finished\n");
        goto cleanup;
 
    return 0;
//cleanup code
}

// Modified processFile function for threading
void *processFile(void *arg) {
    ThreadArg *threadArg = (ThreadArg *)arg;
    // Allocate memory for localOriginLines
    threadArg->localOriginLines = malloc(originCount * sizeof(char **));
    for (int i = 0; i < originCount; ++i) {
        threadArg->localOriginLines[i] = malloc(txtLineCount * sizeof(char *));
        for (int j = 0; j < txtLineCount; ++j) {
            threadArg->localOriginLines[i][j] = NULL; // Corrected type to char*
        }
    }

    for (int lineIndex = threadArg->startLine; lineIndex < threadArg->endLine && lineIndex < txtLineCount; ++lineIndex) {
        char *tsvLine = strdup(tsvLines[lineIndex]);
        if (!tsvLine) {
            perror("Failed to duplicate TSV line for tokenization");
            continue;
        }

        char **tsvTokens = NULL;
        int tsvTokenCount = 0;
        char *saveptr;
        char *token = strtok_r(tsvLine, "\t", &saveptr);
        while (token) {
            char **temp = realloc(tsvTokens, (tsvTokenCount + 1) * sizeof(char *));
            if (temp == NULL) {
                perror("Failed to reallocate memory for tsvTokens");
                break;
            }
            tsvTokens = temp;
            tsvTokens[tsvTokenCount++] = strdup(token);
            token = strtok_r(NULL, "\t", &saveptr);
        }

        for (int originIndex = 0; originIndex < originCount; ++originIndex) {
            const char *txtLineContent = txtLines[lineIndex];
            size_t newLineSize = strlen(txtLineContent) + tsvTokenCount * 2; // Example size calculation
            threadArg->newline = calloc(newLineSize, sizeof(char));
            if (!threadArg->newline) {
                perror("Failed to allocate memory for newLine");
                break; // Skip this line on allocation failure
            }
            threadArg->currentPtr = threadArg->newline;
            
            // Copy initial ID part from txtLineContent, if present
            const char *firstTab = strchr(txtLineContent, '\t');
            size_t idLength = firstTab ? (firstTab - txtLineContent) : 0;
            if (idLength > 0) {
                strncpy(threadArg->currentPtr, txtLineContent, idLength);
                threadArg->currentPtr += idLength;
                *threadArg->currentPtr++ = '\t';
            }

            txtLineContent = firstTab ? firstTab + 1 : txtLineContent;
            for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < tsvTokenCount; ++columnIndex) {
                int tokenValue = atoi(tsvTokens[columnIndex]);
                *threadArg->currentPtr++ = (tokenValue == origins[originIndex].code && columnIndex < strlen(txtLineContent)) ? txtLineContent[columnIndex] : '9';
                if (columnIndex < tsvTokenCount - 1 && columnIndex < strlen(txtLineContent) - 1) {
                    *threadArg->currentPtr++ = '\t';
                }
            }
            *threadArg->currentPtr = '\0';
            threadArg->localOriginLines[originIndex][lineIndex] = strdup(threadArg->newline);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < tsvTokenCount; ++i) {
            free(tsvTokens[i]);
        }
        free(tsvTokens);
        free(tsvLine);
    }

    // Return the localOriginLines for further processing outside the thread
    return threadArg->localOriginLines;
}
```

**Question**:
How can I optimize my C program to improve its performance for processing these large files? Are there specific techniques or changes in my multithreaded approach that could help reduce processing time and avoid disk sleep issues?

Comment: *"File 3: Another large matrix (n x m+1), with columns of 0, 1, 9, and an index column of integer values."* I don't understand what that means. Please give small examples of input and output files.

Comment: What do you mean by *"threads frequently entering disk sleep state"*? Is the disk read/write the bottleneck and CPU usage is low?

Comment: I don't know if this is your actual problem, but one thing that stands out is that there seems to be a lot of dynamic memory allocations (`malloc, calloc, realloc, strdup`): Do you really need to make so much copies? Could you reuse memory for multiple lines, or tokens? And also a lot of string travelsal `strlen, strtok, strchr`: How many times does the same string really have to be processed? Can you cache string length, for example? Note that I didn't look at the source code in detail; just an overall feeling.

Comment: @user694733 I observed in htop that every other second the threads enter in state D for disk sleep. I have no idea why this happens probably due to awaiting some other operation to finsish writing to the memory? 

This is my first more complex program in C so I'm not kinda unsure if your suggestions regarding the memory allocations are reasonable.  For the allocation of ```threadArgs[i]``` and   ```threadArgs[i]->localOriginLines``` I think it is a reasonable approach since I want to use this programs with a flexible size of the nxm matrix.

Comment: @user694733 
String travelsal : Each value of File2 has to be compared against the value from the same row and column index of File 3 after cut and past the index value of the line from File 3 to the newline.

Comment: @user694733 How could I reuse memory for multiple lines or tokens?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256682/discussion-between-mugdi-and-user694733).

Comment: Please give example of output also: Currently it's unclear how files 1, 2, and 3 form the output file. Also, please state in your question how many lines of each of these files are to take 8 hours.

Comment: I added an output example and also clarified my estimate of the program runtime.

Answer (score 1):

With each file being 50000 lines and 17000 columns, so maybe each file is roughly 2 GB. If you duplicate each row and token on each row on multiple threads simultaneously, I would expect a lot of very tiny memory allocations, and eventually you would run out of RAM and start swapping to disk.

I don't think you need all of that memory allocation or copying.

File 1 is not particularly interesting. You read it to memory, and convert it to some kind of key-value list, and start spawning threads for each once. Since you said keys are single digit values, I doubt that this is your bottleneck.

Since you need to read files 2 and 3 multiple times (once for each country, if I understood correctly), I think it makes sense to read both files to RAM at startup, so you don't need to open same files multiple times.

Now, the actual parsing of files 2 and 3:

No allocation, no copying, no `strtok` or `strlen`. Do a simple character search to find next position, and use data from already loaded files 2 and 3 using the offsets you just got. For example:

1. Find first tab separator of file 3. Now you have offsets of line start, which is index start, and index end. Just write that (`111111`) directly to output file, along with tab separator.
2. Find first tab in file 2, and next tab on file 3. Now you have positions of first key, and first value. Just do compare of file 2 key ascii value (key was single digit), no number conversion necessary. Depending on comparison result, just write result directly to output; either value 9 or value from file 3.
3. Keep repeating step 2 until you reach end of line, in which case start from step 1 again.

Important bit is that you only move data, when writing to file (no useless copying or allocations), and you only have minimal times you need access data (for example, no need for `strlen` because we can calculate the field string length from tab offset positions we found.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your ideas. Instead of spawning threads for each country, my idea was to spawn threads for each x lines lets say ```50,000 % 24``` and then perform the comparison and conversion for all countries altogether. Of course then one would need to save this lines and return it for each thread before joining the threads in the end. This is basically what I did so far. So multithread this per country instead of per x lines is the faster approach?

Comment: @mugdi I don't know what is best way to divide for each thread. I simply assumed that would be how you would do that or that it would be simplest division.

Comment: *Since you need to read files 2 and 3 multiple times...*  This is the one use case where `mmap()` might actually be the fastest way to access the data.

Comment: So there is no way to know beforehand the best way to divide the data for each thread?

Comment: @AndrewHenle Can you show me an example how to access data with mmap?