# Fastest approach to split and access mmaped data for each thread

Tags: c, posix, mmap

This questions is related to [this former question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77879651/optimizing-a-multithreaded-c-program-for-processing-large-tsv-files/77880780?noredirect=1#comment137299189_77880780) from which I will copy the most related parts (**Note the change in File2**) :

**Problem Description**:

I've written a multithreaded C program using POSIX to process two large TSV input files. My goal is to generate output files based on these inputs, but I'm facing performance issues.

- *File 1*: Contains country-key pairs (e.g., African 0\nAmerindian 1\n...).
- *File 2*: A large n x m matrix with single digit values corresponding to keys from File 1.

  Example:

  ```
  0\t3\t4\t1\t2...

  0\t3\t4\t1\t2...
  ```
- *File 3*: Another large matrix (n x m+1), with columns of 0, 1, 9, and an index column of integer values which can vary in length .
  Example:

  ```
  111111\t0\t1\t0\t0\t1...

  22222233\t0\t1\t1\t1\t1...
  ```

**Objective**: For each country, I need to create an output file (country.txt) with the same structure as File 3. The output logic depends on matching keys from File 2 with values in File 3.

**Output example**:

For Amerindian.txt with key 1 we copy the first value from File 3, the index, then compare each value to the key value of the specific country. So that we observe a 9 for a mismatch at every position despite position 4 for row in File2 so that at this position we copy the value from File3 which leads to the following output:

```
  111111\t9\t9\t9\t0\t9...

  22222233\t9\t9\t9\t1\t9...
```

In the former question I was pointed to `mmap` in C which was suggested as the fastest approach. I implemented this idea into my program and reworked the `main` and `processing` function. Which looks like the following:

`main:`

```c
//library loading, function,variable and input parameter declaration...
//process origins file
FILE *originsFile = fopen(argv[optind], "r");
originCount = readOrigins(originsFile, &origins);
printf("Number of origins parsed: %d\n", originCount);

//create mmap for 
int tsv_fd = open(argv[optind + 1], O_RDONLY);
int txt_fd = open(argv[optind + 2], O_RDONLY);
struct stat tsv_stat, txt_stat;
fstat(tsv_fd, &tsv_stat);
fstat(txt_fd, &txt_stat);


char *tsv_mapped = mmap(NULL, tsv_stat.st_size, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, tsv_fd, 0);
char *txt_mapped = mmap(NULL, txt_stat.st_size, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, txt_fd, 0);

close(txt_fd);
close(tsv_fd);
// Check for mmap errors
if (tsv_mapped == MAP_FAILED || txt_mapped == MAP_FAILED) {
    perror("Error mapping files");
    // Handle error: close file descriptors, possibly exit
}


// Initialize txtLineCount and tsvLineCount appropriately
txtLineCount = countLinesInFile(txt_mapped, txt_stat.st_size);

//calculate workload for each thread
    int linesPerThread = txtLineCount / numThreads;
    int remainingLines = txtLineCount % numThreads;

//check that workload is reasonable, if txtLineCount exceeds numThreads set numThreads to number of lines
if (txtLineCount < numThreads) {
    numThreads = txtLineCount; // Limit the number of threads to the number of lines
//calculate workload for each thread
    int linesPerThread = txtLineCount / numThreads;
    int remainingLines = txtLineCount % numThreads;
}
    pthread_t threads[numThreads];
    ThreadArg *threadArgs[numThreads];
    
    for (int originIndex = 0; originIndex < originCount; ++originIndex) {
        printf("Processing origin: %s\n", origins[originIndex].name);
    int currentLine = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; ++i) {

printf("Debug: Allocating ThreadArg for thread %d\n", i);

   threadArgs[i] = (ThreadArg *)malloc(sizeof(ThreadArg));
        threadArgs[i]->startLine = currentLine;
        threadArgs[i]->endLine = currentLine + linesPerThread;
        // Assign the memory-mapped file pointers
        if (i < remainingLines) threadArgs[i]->endLine++;
        currentLine = threadArgs[i]->endLine;
        
        threadArgs[i]->tsvMapped = tsv_mapped;
        threadArgs[i]->txtMapped = txt_mapped;
        threadArgs[i]->specificOriginIndex = origins[originIndex].code;
        threadArgs[i]->txt_stat = txt_stat.st_size;
        threadArgs[i]->tsv_stat = tsv_stat.st_size;
        threadArgs[i]->threadnum = i;

        
printf("Debug: Thread %d - startLine: %d, endLine: %d, specificOriginIndex: %d\n", i, threadArgs[i]->startLine, threadArgs[i]->endLine, threadArgs[i]->specificOriginIndex);
   if (pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, processFile, threadArgs[i])) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate memory for thread arguments\n");
//cleanup and return..
```

`processFile and getLinesFromMappedFile`

```c
void *processFile(void *arg) {
    ThreadArg *threadArg = (ThreadArg *)arg;
    char* getLinesFromMappedFile(const char* mappedFile, int startLine, int endLine, size_t fileSize, size_t* byteRange);
    char tempFileName[1024];
    sprintf(tempFileName, "temp_output_%d_%d.tmp", threadArg->specificOriginIndex, threadArg->threadnum);
    FILE *outputFile = fopen(tempFileName, "a"); // Append mode

    if (!outputFile) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open output file.\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    
    size_t byteRangeTsv;
    const char* segmentTsv = getLinesFromMappedFile(threadArg->tsvMapped, 
                                                    threadArg->startLine, 
                                                    threadArg->endLine, 
                                                    threadArg->tsv_stat, 
                                                    &byteRangeTsv);

    size_t byteRangeTxt;
    const char* segmentTxt = getLinesFromMappedFile(threadArg->txtMapped, 
                                                    threadArg->startLine, 
                                                    threadArg->endLine, 
                                                    threadArg->txt_stat, 
                                                    &byteRangeTxt);

    if (!segmentTsv || !segmentTxt) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Lines not found in one of the files.\n");
        if (outputFile) fclose(outputFile);
        return NULL;
    }
    int tsvIndex;
    int txtIndex;
printf("%ld,%ld", byteRangeTsv, byteRangeTxt);
    // Process the segments as per the original logic
    for (size_t tsvIndex = 0, txtIndex = 0; tsvIndex < byteRangeTsv && txtIndex < byteRangeTxt; ) {
        if(txtIndex == 0){        
        // Copy the first index integer from file3 to the output
        while (segmentTxt[txtIndex] != '\t' && segmentTxt[txtIndex] != '\0') {
            fprintf(outputFile, "%c", segmentTxt[txtIndex]);
            txtIndex++;
            tsvIndex++;
        }

        // Skip the tab character in file3
        if (segmentTxt[txtIndex] == '\t') {
            fprintf(outputFile, "\t");
            txtIndex++;
        }
    }
        // Process the lines
        while (segmentTsv[tsvIndex] != '\n' && segmentTxt[txtIndex] != '\n') {
            if (segmentTsv[tsvIndex] == '\t') {
                fprintf(outputFile, "\t");
             txtIndex++; 
             tsvIndex++; 
            }                        
            if (segmentTsv[tsvIndex] == threadArg->specificOriginIndex) {
                fprintf(outputFile, "%c\t", segmentTxt[txtIndex]);
            } else {
                fprintf(outputFile, "9\t");
            }
             txtIndex++; 
             tsvIndex++;
        }

        fprintf(outputFile, "\n");
        // Move to the start of the next line
        while (segmentTsv[tsvIndex] != '\n' && tsvIndex < byteRangeTsv) tsvIndex++;
        while (segmentTxt[txtIndex] != '\n' && txtIndex < byteRangeTxt) txtIndex++;
        if (segmentTsv[tsvIndex] == '\n') tsvIndex++;
        if (segmentTxt[txtIndex] == '\n') txtIndex++;
    }

    fclose(outputFile);
    return NULL;
}


char* getLinesFromMappedFile(const char* mappedFile, int startLine, int endLine, size_t fileSize, size_t* byteRange) {
    if (mappedFile == NULL || startLine < 0 || endLine < startLine) {
        return NULL; // Invalid parameters
    }

    const char* startPtr = NULL;
    const char* endPtr = NULL;
    int currentLine = 0;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < fileSize; ++i) {
        if (currentLine == startLine && startPtr == NULL) {
            startPtr = mappedFile + i; // Set start pointer at the beginning of startLine
        }

        if (mappedFile[i] == '\n') {
            if (currentLine == endLine) {
                endPtr = mappedFile + i; // Set end pointer at the end of endLine
                break;
            }
            currentLine++;
        }
    }

    if (startPtr == NULL) {
        return NULL; // startLine not found
    }

    // If endPtr is not set, use fileSize as end
    if (endPtr == NULL) {
        endPtr = mappedFile + fileSize;
    }

    // Calculate the byte range to read
    *byteRange = endPtr - startPtr;

    return (char*)startPtr; // Cast to non-const to match function signature
}
```

**Question : What is the most efficient approach,  in terms of creating the desired output in the lowest cpu time, to split and access the mmapped-data for each thread?**

Comment: Efficient in terms of *what* resource?

Comment: Are you sure you're running with the most optimized build possible? For simple parsing you should be bumping up against IO limits long before CPU.

Comment: Efficient in terms of creating the desired output in the lowest cpu time.

Comment: @tadman What dou you mean by "most optimized build"?

Comment: As in `-O3` or equivalent for your compiler, not a *debug* build. Too many times I've seen people struggling to get debug builds to run fast, which is not the point, unaware they're driving, effectively, with the parking brake firmly applied.

Comment: This is my first C program to be quite honest. So, I'm sorry that, despite your best effort to explain to me what you mean by "optimized buld", I'm still quite clueless what you suggest to solve the question or what `-03` or equivalent for your compiler means here.

Comment: When you compile programs in C, or most languages for that matter, the resulting executable, while compiled, is not *optimized*, that is it's the most elementary form of executable. This makes debugging significantly easier since the resulting executable maps quite neatly to your code. Optimized builds do all kinds of things that may not make sense, but result in *significant* performance improvements. Before you tackle anything sophisticated, be **absolutely sure** you've enabled all applicable optimizations, though usually `-O3` or equivalent is fine.

Comment: So when I should do `gcc path/to/myprogramm -O3` to compile my executable?

Comment: What build system, if any, are you using here? Normally as a baseline you have a `Makefile`, but some prefer CMake or other tools. A good `Makefile` template will have settings for both debug and "release" (optimized) builds.

Comment: I just do `gcc path/to/myprogramm -mylibraries` to compile my program and then use the resulting executable to run my program. I thought this is already good to go.

Comment: That's just a debug build and those are often ten times (or more, depending on what you're doing!) slower than a fully optimized release build.

Comment: Wow. That is probably the most helpful information I got so far.  Could you do me one last favor and check if my `getLinesFromMappedFile` implementation makes sense?

Comment: It's not clear what the intent is there. If this important code that needs to work correctly, I'd suggest leveraging a [unit testing framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unit_testing_frameworks) that you can use to validate each function before testing the entire app together (integration).

Comment: I tried to write a function that gets a startLine, an endLine and a mmaped data address and then should search for this data block (startLine to endLine) in the mmaped data and return this data. I thought of the most basic approach to access some mmaped data.